# Routing table routes with different administrative distance

Tags: routing, administrative-distance

When a router receives two routes from the same routing protocol to the same destination network, it uses the Metric to decide which one to add to the routing table, so if Metric was different it will add only one of them (The one with the lowest Metric) and  if both have the same Metric then it will load balance between them .

Now if the router receives two routes from two different routing protocols (Example: RIP and OSPF) for the same destination network, does the router adds both of them to the routing table (adds the second as backup route maybe and uses the route with lowest AD to route packets) or will only add the one with the lowest Administrative Distance to the routing table ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and quick: Only the route with better (lower) admin distance is added to the routing table.